# How to add Github raw repositories to Sonatype Nexus as Proxy repository?

Tags: maven, github, nexus

Nowadays there are a lot of github hosted Maven repositories. 
ex) https://github.com/nhnopensource/nhnopensource.maven.repo

I tried to add those repositories into my Sonatype Nexus repository manager as proxy repository, but failed all the time.

But the repositories work fine when I set repository url directly to the github repositories in gradle/maven configuration.

Has anybody succeeded to add github hosted maven repository into Nexus?

Comment: I tried [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview), and it works nicely with github raw repositories.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution : https://github.com/sagemintblue/sagemintblue-repositories

> If you use Sonatype's Nexus repository manager, you may want to add
>   proxy entries to your Nexus configuration for the Sagemintblue
>   repositories. Here are a few notes to keep in mind:
>
> Sagemintblue repositories don't contain indices. You should set Remote Repository Access > Download Remote Indexes to false.
>
> Because GitHub doesn't generate directory listings for raw repository directory URLs, Nexus will automatically block the proxied
>   repositories if Remote Repository Access > Auto blocking active is set
>   to true. Set this option to false and click Refresh. You should see a
>   Repository Status of Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable. Nexus
>   should still be able to access specific artifact, pom and checksum
>   file URLs despite the missing directory listings.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with this repo may be that it doesn't have index.html, and so Nexus cannot "crawl" it... I'm not 100% sure, but I remember having encountered something similar when I set-up my own https://github.com/vorburger/m2p2-repository.  If that's not it, try posting on nexus-user@sonatype.org and when you've figured it out post the correct response here! ;-) PS: http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2013/08/deploying-github-hosted-maven-incl.html may also be of interest to you?

Comment: Your guess is right. I found the solution. https://github.com/sagemintblue/sagemintblue-repositories
It works!