# How to use Sonatype Nexus Repository Groups with Github raw repositories?

Tags: maven, github, nexus

How can I tell Nexus to download the artifacts from a raw github maven repository when the Proxy Repository in Nexus is in a **Repository Group**?

Background: In our parent-pom we use a catch all mirror, so we don't have to configure each and every repository to the poms. This works flawless and is also common practice - example:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>provided</id>
        <url>http://nexus.host/content/groups/provided</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

But when using a raw github repository this dosn't works. How can I configure Nexus to do this?

Note: I already  read "[How to add Github raw repositories to Sonatype Nexus as Proxy repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991752/how-to-add-github-raw-repositories-to-sonatype-nexus-as-proxy-repository)", but this doesn't tells you how it would run with Repository Groups.

Update: In a manual post step I created the nexus index files with the [nexus-indexer-3.0.4-cli.jar](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Nexus+Indexer), and commited/pushed them to github. Now nexus shows me in the "Browse Index" tab the files in the Proxy Repository, but the problem remains. Clients can not download the artifacts from Nexus.

Comment: Did you add the new proxy repository to the provided group that you are accessing Nexus with?

Comment: @ManfredMoser Thanks, I really did forget to add the proxy to the group. If you leave it as answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the proxy repository, you have to add it to the group through which you are accessing Nexus in your build tool. In your case it seems that group uses the id "provided" as visible from the url in the mirror.

See more about adding to repository groups in the Nexus book [here](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-repo-group.html) and [here](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-groups.html)

Comment: Which remote address should be added for Github repository?

Comment: You can not proxy git repositories with Nexus.